# Send push notifications to devices at specific time set by the user using Azure functions and Notification hubs

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to send notifications to user's mobile devices registered on **azure notification hub** at specific time set by the user to receive notification. To do this, I am using **azure TimerTrigger functions** to trigger the function every **1 minute** to read notification details from DB and send that information to azure notification hub, so that it can send notifications.

My question is can I send notifications to registered devices using azure notification hub at a specific time set by the users?

The above approach is correct? or is there any better way to do the same using resources on **Azure**

Answer (score 0):

Where you're currently populating your database, you could also setup a NotificationHub [ScheduledSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-send-push-notifications-scheduled). This will reduce how frequently you have to read your database. However, a scheduled send is not a recurrent operation. So if your user wants to be notified once a day, you'll still need to enqueue a new scheduled message once a day.

At time of writing, scheduled sends are only available on the paid "Standard" SKU. Notification Hubs is pretty cheap though, so it may pay off to use Azure functions less often.

Comment: Thanks Mar for the advice. I am currently populating the data in **azure postgresql** when a user selects an option in the **mobile app**. I will have to send the notification **after 24 hours** of the time set by the user, means next day. I am using **Scheduled** send at the moment but as you said it is part of **Standard SKU** so not sure if I will use it because it costs so much. "_what you mean by pay off to use Azure functions less often_"

Comment: Looks like Azure Functions are cheaper than I was giving them credit for. You'll have to do the math to figure out what makes sense for your budget and scenario.